# How do I compare row count in a MYSQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have this SQL Table

```
id | name | date
1  | as   | 0000-00-00
1  | df   | 0000-00-00
1  | fg   | 0000-00-00
1  | hj   | 0000-00-00
2  | xc   | 2011-2-32
2  | op   | 2011-3-21
3  | er   | 2011-2-43
4  | po   | 0000-00-00
4  | ui   | 0000-00-00
```

I want to get the id that has 4 rows of date which has a value of 0000-00-00, which would be 1

The SQL statement Im thinking of is something like this...
(This is obviously wrong)

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE COUNT(date = 0000-00-00) = 4
```

I'm open to other answers in case you have a better/efficient solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT id, count(*)
FROM table1
WHERE date = 0000-00-00
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, count(id)
FROM table1
WHERE date = '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're looking for

```
SELECT id, count(id)
FROM table1
WHERE date = 0000-00-00
HAVING count(id) = 4
GROUP BY id
```